# QML mapbox classic tile style is not supporting for the 6.5.0 version

Tags: qt, qml, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import QtLocation
import QtPositioning
import QtLocation 6.5

Window {
    width: 512
    height: 512
    visible: true

    Plugin {
        id: mapPlugin
        name: "mapbox"
        PluginParameter {
            name: "mapbox.access_token"
            value: "pk.eyJ1IjoidmVnYWlubm92YXRpb25zIiwiYSI6ImNsbTV3c3hwZDA4ZDgzcGxna2IxbDfQ.eVpetpE1_nHx3K-LRMPb0g"


    }
  Map {
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: mapPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(60.170448, 24.942046)
        zoomLevel: 12
    } 
}
```

I am trying to render the Mapbox map here, but I am getting this error

`QGeoTileRequestManager: Failed to fetch tile (2332,1184,12) 5 times, giving up. Last error message was: 'Error transferring https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/12/2332/1184.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoidmVnYWlubm92YXRpb25zIiwiYSI6ImNsbTV3c3hwZDA4ZDgzcGxna2IxbDZtNXMifQ.eVpetpE1_nK-LRMPb0g - server replied: Gone'`

it says the classic style maps are not supporting. Just help me to render the map to the window.
Thanks a lot

Comment: why do you make a conclusion that the classic style maps are not supporting? what is  the classic style btw?

Comment: Thanks for replying https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/static-tiles/
In the mapbox documentation they saying that the classic styles are no longer supporting, so I made a new style using mapbox studio and added the above access token but I am getting the same error saying classic styles nor supporting although I changes the map style. I made a get request to the above error
and got message "Classic styles are no longer supported; see https://blog.mapbox.com/deprecating-studio-classic-styles-d8892ac38cb4 for more information"
Thanks alot

Comment: please help me to render just map in any style, I do not know whether the error is in my code or with the access token, Please help me render the map in the window that is all I need.
Thanks a lot